# Does within 5 years mean before or after?

Tags: meaning

Does within 5 years mean before or after the end of December?

For example if the someone says, "you cannot have committed a crime within 5 years of the date 9/22/2010". Does this mean before September 22nd or after December? Please help?

Comment: If the date was 1/1/2010 and your December hypothesis were correct, then your 5 years would effectively be 6 ...

Comment: Technically, the phrase could refer to the ten years surrounding 9/22/2010—that is, 9/22/2010 ± 5 years. But realistically it is probably meant cover the period from 9/22/2010 through 9/22/2015.

Answer (score 3):

It means between 9/22/2010 to 9/22/2015.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, *within 5 years* could mean either side of a given date, covering a total of ten years altogether. It could be before, after or both. 
I think you just have to use your common sense depending on the context.